# Problem with the code. Circular reference detected

Tags: python, list, telegram-bot, openai-api

I'm new to python and decided to try to make a chatbot based on openai in Telegram. After exceeding 4096 tokens I wanted to make it so that old messages are deleted (but not all but the oldest ones until there is not enough room for new ones) from the context, so the AI would remember past messages. But for some reason, when the token limit exceeds 4096 - it writes "role", and when sending a message again, the error "Circular reference detected" comes out.

```
import openai
import config
import telebot
import re
import time
from openai.error import RateLimitError, InvalidRequestError

openai.api_key = config.openai_token
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.telegram_token)

max_context_tokens = 4096 - 300
context = []

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main(message):
    try:
        global context
        prompt = message.text
        if not prompt.strip():
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="1")
        context.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
        trimmed_context = trim_context_by_tokens(context, max_context_tokens)
        ans = get_response(prompt, trimmed_context, context)
        context.append({"role": "assistant", "content": ans})
        print(context)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=ans)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

def get_response(prompt: str, trimmed_context: list, context: list) -> str:
    messages = [{'role': 'system',
                 'content': "text1"},
                {'role': 'system',
                 'content': "text2"},
                {'role': 'system',
                 'content': "text3"}] + trimmed_context
    messages.append({'role': 'user', 'content': prompt})

    try:
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0301',
            messages=messages,
            temperature=1.0,
            max_tokens=300,
            top_p=1.0,
            frequency_penalty=0.7,
            presence_penalty=0.7,
            stop=None
        )
        print(completion['usage']['total_tokens'])
        return completion['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    except RateLimitError as e:
        print("Speed limit exceeded. Try again in 5 seconds...")
        time.sleep(5)
    except InvalidRequestError:
        trim_context_by_tokens(context, max_context_tokens)
        print("Exceeded token limit. Retry...")
        return context
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error has occurred: {e}.")
        raise e

def count_tokens(text: str) -> int:
    return len(re.findall(r'\w+', text))

def trim_context_by_tokens(context: list, max_tokens: int) -> list:
    total_tokens = sum(count_tokens(msg['content']) for msg in context)
    while total_tokens > max_tokens:
        removed_message = context.pop(0)
        total_tokens -= count_tokens(removed_message['content'])
    print("input: ", context)
    return context

bot.polling()
```

I tried just deleting the very first reply of the bot when the maximum number of tokens is reached, also did not help

Comment: Can you provide the exact details to reproduce your error? From what you describe, there may be more than one possible issue. For example, "the very first reply of the bot when the maximum number of tokens is reached" might not guarantee that you're under the token max if the new input puts it  over by more than (max_tokens - first_message_tokens)